# Zend Framework 2 how to trigger MvcEvent in ListenerAggregateInterface

Tags: triggers, zend-framework2, listener

**I want to trigger error event in my listener and send a custom http status code (409) - see onEvent**

I've attached my listeners via listener config

```
return [
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'SendFeedListener' => 'MyModule\Listener\SendFeedListener',
    ),
),
'listeners' => array(
    'SendFeedListener',
),
];
```

my listener:

```
class SendFeedListener implements ListenerAggregateInterface, ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait, ConfigAwareTrait;

/**
 * @var \Zend\Stdlib\CallbackHandler[]
 */
protected $listeners = [];

public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events)
{
    $sharedEvents = $events->getSharedManager();
    $this->listeners[] = $sharedEvents->attach(
        'MyModule\\Service\\MyService',
        '*', // listen for all events
        array($this, 'onEvent'),
        100
    );
}

...

public function onEvent(EventInterface $e)
{
   // ... some code

   // it went wrong, I want to trigger some error
   if($this->getMyService()->doSomething() == false) {
     $mvcEvent = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('application')->getMvcEvent();
     $this->getServiceLocator()->get('application')
     ->getEventManager()
     ->trigger(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, $mvcEvent);
   }
 }
...
}
```

}

what I can do is something like the following:

```
// something went wrong
$sharedEvents = $e->getTarget()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
$sharedEvents->attach('Zend\\Mvc\\Application', MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER,
            array($this, 'errorResponse'), -10000);

public function errorResponse($e)
{
    $response = $e->getResponse();
    $response->setStatusCode(409);
    $response->setContent((new JsonModel($this->error->toArray()))->serialize());
}
```

but it looks totally crazy

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$e->setError('my-custom-error');
$e->getTarget()->getEventManager()->trigger('dispatch.error', $e);
```

i am not sure 100%, but if i remember correctly you can only trigger `dispatch.error` during `onRoute` and before `dispatch` is triggered.